# OneToOne autofill with the parent's value

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Seccion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["pk"]

class Contenido(models.Model):
    title = models.OneToOneField(
        Seccion, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        verbose_name ="Título",
        )
    exp = RichTextField(blank=True)
    practice = RichTextField(blank=True,verbose_name="Buenas 
Prácticas")
    lecture = RichTextField(blank=True)
    ending = RichTextField(blank=True)
    recomendations = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title.name
```

So, I have those models, I'd like to know if there's a way to autofill the title with the parent's value "name".

Answer (score 0):

**title** is a `OneToOneField`, so it must contain a reference to another model's entry, you can not put a text in it. Nevertheless, you can reference parent's title like this:

```
print(contenido_instance.title.name)
```